# jQuery sortable images that is droppable on separate containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

[image: Sample Image]

Sorry for the ugly illustration I attached. I'm a beginner so please bear with me. I have an image attached below.

1.) This is the normal structure of the page. IMG 1-4 and CONTAINER 1-4 are images. IMG 1-4 are draggable images which will then be dragged on to the containers which are CONTAINER 1-4. CONTAINER 1-4 are not draggable.

2.) IMG 1 is dragged on CONTAINER 1 (the illustration was wrong! I'M VERY SORRY! CONTAINER 1 should be IMG 1 now!). So CONTAINER 1 now is IMG 1 (like a puzzle). What I would also like is that it would snap automatically on to the container if it is dragged on it's square area of the container and it has some highlight colour when it is dragged. Then IMG 1 now is gone as it is placed on CONTAINER 1.

3.) Now on this scenario the images are placed on its associated containers.

4.) So after the images are placed on its associated containers, it is also sortable because the order of the images are important. Each order of the images has unique combination value. Then there will be a submit button on the bottom which will then be submitted on the server.

As for now, I'm only halfway and it seems that I can't solve my problem. Here's what I've tried so far:

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(".drag-card-icon").draggable({ cursor: "crosshair", revert: "invalid"});
$(".drag-card-group").droppable({ accept: ".drag-card-icon",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().appendTo(droppedOn);
    },
    over: function(event, elem) {
        $(this).addClass("over");
        console.log("over");
    },
    out: function(event, elem) {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
});
$(".drag-card-group").sortable();

$(".drag-card-container-origin").droppable({ accept: ".drag-card-icon", drop: function(event, ui) {
    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var droppedOn = $(this);
    $(dropped).detach().appendTo(droppedOn);
}});
```

**HTML:**

```
                      <form action="#">
                        <div class="form-group form-row drag-card-container-origin">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src="/images/image-1" class="drag-card-item drag-card-icon">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src="/images/image-2" class="drag-card-item drag-card-icon">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src="/images/image-3" class="drag-card-item drag-card-icon">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src="/images/image-4" class="drag-card-item drag-card-icon">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <h6 class="text-uppercase">
                                DROP YOUR IMAGES BELOW
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-row drag-card-container">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src="/images/container-1.png" class="drag-card-item drag-card-group draggable="false">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src="/images/container-2.png" class="drag-card-item drag-card-group draggable="false">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src="/images/container-3.png" class="drag-card-item drag-card-group draggable="false">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <img src="/images/container-4.png" class="drag-card-item drag-card-group draggable="false">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Not sure why you are using Droppable and Sortable. Sortable can accept Draggable elements. If you want the user to place each image before sorting, I would use Droppable; then, when each item is placed, you can use Sortable. Also your questions is almost too vague or too ambiguous to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you want to `.append()` an `<img>` into another `<img>`. Either replace the img, the image src, or hide and append. Here is an example fo the last method.

```js
$(function() {
  function countFilled() {
    return $(".filled").length;
  }

  $(".drag-card-icon").draggable({
    cursor: "crosshair",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $(".drag-card-group").droppable({
    accept: ".drag-card-icon",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dropped = ui.draggable;
      var droppedOn = $(this);
      if (droppedOn.is(":visible")) {
        console.log("Hiding Group");
        droppedOn.addClass("hidden").hide().parent().addClass("filled");
      }
      $(dropped).detach().attr("style", "").insertBefore(droppedOn);
      droppedOn.droppable("disable");
      if (countFilled() == 4) {
        $(".hidden").droppable("destroy").remove();
        $(".drag-card-icon").draggable("destroy");
        $(".drag-card-container").sortable({
          items: "> div.col-sm-3"
        });
      }
    },
    over: function(event, elem) {
      $(this).addClass("over");
      console.log("over");
    },
    out: function(event, elem) {
      $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
  });

  $(".drag-card-container-origin").droppable({
    accept: ".drag-card-icon",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dropped = ui.draggable;
      var droppedOn = $(this);
      $(dropped).detach().appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.drag-card-container-origin .col-sm-3,
.drag-card-container .col-sm-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <div class="form-group form-row drag-card-container-origin">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/a9a9a9/ffffff&text=Image+1" class="drag-card-item drag-card-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/a9a9a9/ffffff&text=Image+2" class="drag-card-item drag-card-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/a9a9a9/ffffff&text=Image+3" class="drag-card-item drag-card-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/a9a9a9/ffffff&text=Image+4" class="drag-card-item drag-card-icon">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h6 class="text-uppercase">
      DROP YOUR IMAGES BELOW
    </h6>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-row drag-card-container">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/000000/ffffff&text=Contain+1" class="drag-card-item drag-card-group" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/000000/ffffff&text=Contain+2" class="drag-card-item drag-card-group" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/000000/ffffff&text=Contain+3" class="drag-card-item drag-card-group" draggable="false">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/000000/ffffff&text=Contain+4" class="drag-card-item drag-card-group" draggable="false">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for helping out! Bless you! One last thing though, is it possible that on number 4, the images cannot be placed either on each other but it is draggable only on order. So for example the order is IMG 1, IMG 2, IMG 3, IMG 4 and if the user drags IMG 4 to the first, then the order would be IMG 4, IMG 1, IMG 2, IMG 3.

Comment: @user3233787 yes it is possible. This was not part of your original post and sound like that will be your next challenge. I am happy to help point out issues and help nudge you in the right direction. Otherwise, I am not going to write your code for you without compensation.

Comment: Got it. Thank you sir!